# How can i add a table in my existing database without losing data in Entity-framework Code first 5.0 ?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Recently I updated my software and I need to add a new table in my database. I am using

```
Update-Database -Force -Verbose
```

to update my database in my development PC. But when I install update version of my software in my client machine then it throw following exception.

```
The model backing the ‘MyContext’ context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)
```

If I drop and recreate database then it`s work fine.

But it is quite impossible to drop existing database in my client machine. I have to add my new table without losing any data.

Please tell me how can i add a new table without out losing data in my existing Database.

I am using

```
Visual Studio 2012
Entity Framework 5.0
DotNet 4.0
MSSQL Server 2008 R2
```

Comment: Did you follow the link to learn about Code First Migrations?  That's how to update your database without dropping it using EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh770484%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). When you set up your DbContext it will look something like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<dbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<dbContext, Configuration>());
```